# Best way to use/tweak SUS for Enterprise Applications?

Tags: enterprise, sus

I was wondering if there was a vetted type of questionnaire developed for Enterprise applications that modifies the questions that may not apply to a given system.

- Examples:

Systems like a timesheet application are not something someone would choose to use for any other reason except they need to use it to get paid, so I doubt anyone would strongly agree to "I think I would like to use this system frequently".

For systems in already in use, when gaining a baseline measure, the question "I think I would need the support of a technical person to be able to use the system" may generate odd responses because the individuals that are required to use the system may have years of experience with it.

I would like to use the SUS to baseline where we are at before a redesign, so are there any processes/guidelines for tweaking the SUS to get reliable results in situations like this? Does a modified SUS already exist?

I am aware that similar questions have been asked ([SUS Scores and Doubts](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/5211/sus-scores-and-doubts/5214#5214)),

Answer (score -1):

I am not aware of any tweaked versions of SUS however you may find the following useful. Jim Lewis wrote [this article](http://www.measuringu.com/blog/nps-sus.php) in 2012 for Measuring Usability

The article explains the direct correlation found between SUS scores and Net Promoter Scores (NPS). They found that it was possible to predict NPS scores based on SUS scores, which means the inverse is also true.

The Net Promoter Score may make more sense to users already comfortable with your enterprise app.

Comment: I dont think so! NPS is measuring the likelyhood of recommending a company or product, not the usability of a website. A company may be very recommendable or the product is really good, but the website is a nightmare. You cant compare apples and oranges.

Comment: If the product is the said website, than it might work. If the website is a vale-added-service or just a shop for getting the product it wont work. I had one questionnaire with a good rated NPS and a horrible usability rating. One just uses the website for purchasing it. But the product is quite good.